# Bash sort command not sorting colored output correctly

Tags: bash, sorting, colors

When using `/bin/sort` in bash I find that output is often inappropriately sorted when it comes from colorized input.

For example in a directory with the following contents:

```
$ ls
dir1          (directory, printed in blue)
dir2          (directory, printed in blue)
dir3          (directory, printed in blue)
afile         (file, printed in white)
file1         (file, printed in white)
file2         (file, printed in white)
file3         (file, printed in white)
```

I would expect `ls | sort` to sort `afile` first, then `dir1`, etc.  Instead I get:

```
$ ls | sort
dir2
dir3
dir1
afile
file1
file2
file3
```

I have tried quite a few options on `sort` (-d, -g, -h, -n) to no avail.

The only way I have been able to fix the issue is by explicitly turning the color output of `ls` off:

```
$ ls --color=never | sort
afile
dir1
dir2
dir3
file1
file2
file3
```

But this feels like a work-around, not a solution to the problem.  I keep thinking there must be a way to keep the color in the final output, if only for cases where turning off the color is not an option (e.g. for commands other than `ls` that may not easily support disabling color).

How would one force sort to act only on the printed characters (i.e. just the file and directory names)?  I would be interested to see how to cleanly remove the color output after the fact (I've tried `strings` for this but get the color specifiers `[01;34m` for the blue text) and especially interested in whether one can preserve the color output after sorting.

Comment: When output to a pipe `ls` should be disabling colors by default. If that isn't happening that means you have likely accidentally enabled colors with `--color=always` instead of just using `--color`.

Comment: Use `\ls | sort` to disable an alias for `ls`.

Comment: It should be enough to use `--color=auto`, right? It suppresses color when writing to a pipe, and you don't have to fiddle with the options. [Edit: I see that's what @Etan is saying too.]

Comment: sort can only sort what you present it. To keep the color, you'd have to build a pre-filter that move the `color` codes to (maybe) a 2nd and 3rd column, and then a post-fitler to put the colors back (IMHO). Good luck.

Comment: These are all good points, `--color` seems to default to `always` on my system which makes sense of why I'm seeing what I am. The idea of filtering the color codes to a separate column is an interesting idea for preserving it but seems like something that might be a little tricky to get working. I've also just thought of using the `-F` option for the case of `ls` which would at least still provide a designator for the files type. Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Comment: @thesquaregroot This would not be a factory default. Run `alias` and see if you've previously aliased `ls` to `ls --color=always`.

Comment: Why do you need to sort the output of `ls`? It's already sorted.

Comment: @thatotherguy: I have `ls` aliased to `ls --color --group-directories-first`.  @rici that may also address your concern. That said, I was also listing multiple directories and trying to sort the output when I encountered this (in which case it is not sorted whether my alias is there or not).  Regardless, I posted the question largely out of interest about the idea in general, `ls` just happened to also be a good example of a common command with color output.

Comment: @thesquaregroot info says "Specifying '--color' and no WHEN is equivalent to '--color=always'." so regardless of the solution and circumstances here, you should change that to `--color=auto`

Comment: @thesquaregroot: OK, fair enough. It's useful to know the actual application because there are not *that* many applications which automatically colour output, and fewer which produce output which might meaningfully be sorted; the precise solution is different for lines which are entirely coloured (as in my answer) from output where part of the lines might be coloured (no example springs to mind, but if you have one, please feel free to add it to the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text is colored by adding ANSI colour sequences of the form `\x1b[...m`, where the `...` is replaced by one or more numbers separated by semicolons, which describe the style. In order to sort the text, you would need to ignore the entire color sequence, which is well beyond the capabilities of the standard locale collation definition.

If the coloured output is produced by a program like `ls`, which colours each line independently, you could use sed to create a sort key -- the line with colour sequences deleted -- followed by the fully coloured line.

Here's a simple solution which requires that the <kbd>TAB</kbd> is not present in any line. (It also requires that there are no newlines in any entry, but that was required by the fact that entries are individual lines, which is a basic premise for using `sort`.)

```
ls -U --color=always |  # Sample data input
sed 'h;s/\x1b[[0-9;]*m//g;G;s/\n/\t/' | # Insert the sort key
sort |                  # Sort the result
cut -f2-                # Remove the sort key
```

Explanation of the `sed` command:

```
h                   Copy the line to the hold space
s/\x1b[[0-9;]*m//g  Remove all colour sequences
G                   Append a newline and the contents of the hold space
s/\n/\t/            Change the newline to a tab
```

Note: Using backslash escapes other than `\n` in the sed pattern and replacement is a Gnu extension, probably also available in other sed implementations but not required by the Posix standard. For a Posix standard sed, you'll need to replace `\x1b` and `\t` with a binary ESC and TAB respectively.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why do you need `sort` when `ls` has a ton of ordering options built in? Maybe you can solve your problem by reading the manual for `ls`.

But supposing you do need color-insensitive sorting: You can tell `sort` to start sorting after a specified number of characters, which is not quite what you need but it's better than nothing. I don't have your version of `ls` so I can't check for sure, but simple colored text is normally activated with a five-character sequence. E.g., blue is `^[[34m`. So, tell `sort` to start sorting with the sixth character:

```
ls | sort -k 1.6
```

But what about ordinary files? They probably don't get a color prefix, so the above will fail badly unless you filter it to add an equal number of characters in front of black lines. For symmetry you could simply add black color (`^[[00m`, to make it five characters).

```
ls | perl -pe '{ s/^/\e\[00m/ unless /^\e\[/ }' | sort -k 1.6
```